# Is it POSSIBLE to make a 5.5 years old laptop work like new?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, hp-pavilion

I need your help asap!!!!

I have a HP Pavilion DV6-6b51ea laptop which has the following:

- Processor: Intel core i5-2430M CPU @ 2.40 GHz
- RAM: 6 GB
- Bit: 64 bit OS
- Video graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6490M
- Video memory: 1 GB DDR5 dedicated, up to 4 GB total
- Hard Drive: 750 GB SATA (5400 rpm)
- Display: 15.6"
- OS: Genuine Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit

I bought this laptop in Feb 2012 from UK. In June 2016, an incident happened: I was using the laptop on my duvet and suddenly the laptop turned off making a weird sound from the inside (may be from the fan inside or hdd, not sure). Then I turned on the laptop but the screen shows only white lines (the screen is gone). Then I took my laptop to a pc shop and they said I have to change the laptop screen. And I told them about the noise, they said it came from fan/hdd.

I did not repair the laptop. The laptop was unusable as the screen was damaged. I turned on the laptop sometimes, I could not see anything on the screen, but I  assumed that the OS was working (as I could see the blinking of fingerprint reader light).
I kept my laptop 1 year without repairing. Finally, some days ago, I went to a pc shop and they replaced the laptop screen, the keyboard (some keys were not working) and the battery (the backup time of old battery was less). I bought a cooking pad as well to place under the laptop while using. They also completely opened the laptop and cleaned the dust inside, replaced the cooking gum under the chip(s), cleaned the cooling fan etc. 
P.S: When they replaced the screen and turned on the laptop, the Windows 7 lock screen came. Then I accessed to my desktop using fingerprint reader (because I forgot the password that I set 1 year ago). I found all my files (over 500 GB) in the hdd as well.

The laptop is not running in the speed that I saw in 2012. The speed has become slow. I have done a Factory Reset (original factory condition) using HP Recovery Manager software. The speed is still slow, but a little bit less slow. Sometimes, the OS freezes. Yesterday, a Blue screen of death appeared (2 google chrome window were opened, 7 tabs in one window, 9 tabs in another, but I was doing work in only 1 tab, the other tabs were webpages doing nothing)

P:S: I deleted all my files before the factory reset.

Is it "really possible" to make my laptop work like new? I mean- is it "really" possible to get the performance which I used to get in 2012?

Please help me!!

P:S: I did not take that much care of my laptop. 2-3 times my laptop felt from bed. For first 2-3 years, I did not use any cool pad under my laptop. I used to place my laptop on the bed sheet or duvet (when I lied on my bed). There are some cosmetic damage in my laptop, for which I am responsible. Some of the cosmetic damages are fixed using super glue, by the pc store staff.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get your laptop working the way it did when it was new. 

The BSOD could be caused by hardware issues, maybe the HDD, but to know for sure you'd have to share the error codes. 

In other news, you could try a Linux distro, Linux runs great on older hardware.

Comment: In theory the answer to your title is no, simply because software doesn't remain unchanged for 5.5 years. E.g.  modern chrome guzzles way more RAM than it did a few years ago.

Comment: @jiggunjer. Does the hardware get weaker as time goes?

Comment: Is it possible the laptop is running at the speed it was 2012, but your perception, or maybe expectation, of it has changed? This is a common thing with old technology...

Comment: my expectation has not changed. I just want to see it running like 2012

Comment: You probably could have got a new and _faster_ laptop cheaper than a screen replacement for the old one.

Comment: @John "Does the hardware get weaker as time goes?" - No. 
There are very few exceptions for things that have mechanical wear, such as spinning disks.

Comment: 1 thing to mention:  the pc staff said that the cooling gum were almost hard, thats why he placed new cooling gum.
Is it possible that due to poor (almost hard) cooling gum and overheating (I used to place laptop on the duvet without any cooling pad, that means the ventilators could not function properly), the chips (eg- processor) got weaker?

Comment: by cooling gum, i meant ''thermal paste''

Comment: @RJFalconer. You mean, a 5 year old core i5 2430M and a ''brand new'' core i5 2430M will give the same performance?  (considering the old one was in a laptop which went through overheating many times)

Comment: @John Yes, I am certain.

Comment: Depends on what you want to use it for. My answer is generally yes. I still use my Dell Inspirion 1501 with Windows XP and it works flawlessly.

Comment: but nothing is eternal. Is there any proof that a new Core i5 and another Core i5 (identical) running intensively for ten years will give the SAME performance? Is there any solid proof?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your laptop has a HDD and not a SSD, that 5.5 years old HDD may be a problem.

Software part:
You should first try defragmentation.

If this doesn't help, or in the past you  ever heard the clicking sound coming from HDD, no matter just one time, then it's time to replace that HDD, because nothing except fan, HDD, DVD tray  has moving parts, and a BSOD is typical in this type of HDD.

You may want to give a live Linux distro a try, because they don't use the HDD on live session (Mint Linux, Lubuntu etc. don't need HDD for live session).

Grab one on Usb Flash Drive and boot from it (I would disconnect the HDD to be sure).

If you're satisfied by speed of pc in this setup then HDD is faulty.

Next thing: Try attaching the HDD to another laptop if you can. Does it slow down that laptop too?

If the HDD is okay, then focus on other removable hardware. Test each one separately, only then you can pinpoint the problem.

Comment: does the hardware inside the laptop damages/get weaker as time goes?

Comment: the only weird sound i heard is when my screen got damaged

Comment: but i am not sure whether the sound came from hdd or fan?  (as hdd seems to work)

Comment: nothing is eternal my friend!!!

Comment: nothing is eternal my friend!!! hardware with moving part will get weaker quickly  than hardware with no movable part..you cant avoid it ..caring only delays  the inevitable......

Comment: @John Depends on the hardware. After being mostly broken, HDDs can sometimes keep working at horribly slow speeds for a prolonged period of time. Other reasons for slow down are antivirus software or performance throttling on the CPU due to overheating (often caused by bad cooling).

Comment: will my laptop support a SATA 3 hard drive (5400 rpm)?

Comment: Some hard facts needed. What is the SMART status of the hard disk? (slow HDD due to retries) What is the actual processor speed? What is the usual CPU temperature? (CPU throttled to not overheat). What is th RAM size?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you need to wipe your hard drive and completely reinstall the OS. Back up anything you may need to an external USB hard drive.

If the problem persists I would ask the same shop to run a diagnostic on your hard drive. You may need a new hard drive.

It's still a good laptop though. I have a 2011 laptop with similar specs and it still chews trough all of the software. Well some of the latest are too much for it, but I can still play most of them if I turn the video settings down to minimum. I just need to give it some semi regular maintenance. Though my laptops speed might be because I use Linux, not Windows.

On another note I am in the process of restoring a 2004 IBM Thinkpad. But those things were rugged, built to be used on construction sites. And again I am putting Linux on it.(It would probably work with XP as well, as I bought it with Windows 7 on it)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check bad sectors in hard drive.the sluggishness also happen bcoz of bad sector. to check those you can try minitool partition wizard and run surface test. or download dlc boot and run some test on hdd health.